# Please make me understand assigning derived class object to base class pointer- C++

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance

Lets say you have a base class **Base** and derived class **Derived**.

```
Base b;
Derived *d;
d=&b; // this line gives error, why? I think it asks for typecasting, why?
//When you assign derived class object address to base class pointer, it works fine. Why not the above case works fine
```

While below code works,

```
Derived *d=new Base(); //no typecasting required here, why?
```

What's the difference between above two cases?

Thanks!

Comment: "I think it asks for typecasting" What's the *actual* error you get when compiling the code?

Comment: Error: A value of type Base cannot be assigned to an entity of type Derived.
As i know, there we need typecasting. How? and Why?

Comment: What compiler do you get the second example to "work" on? Because it shouldn't.

Answer (score 6):

`Base` *is-not-a* `Derived`, so neither this:

```
Base b;
Derived *d;
d=&b;
```

nor this:

```
Derived* d = new Base();
```

makes any sense or works. Both would result in something like

> error: invalid conversion from 'Base*' to 'Derived*' [-fpermissive]

Both are doing exactly the same thing: assigning a `Base*` to a `Derived*`.

Comment: How to assign the derived class object to base class?

Comment: @SmaugTheDragon: That way round, the pointer or reference conversion is safe, so it can just be done implicitly, e.g. `Base * b = new Derived;`